# vb.net, Termie and threading and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm porting a subset of [Termie](http://termie.sourceforge.net/) (C# version of Termite) to vb.net.  I've worked with this app in C# and adapted it to do some work for me successfully.  This time though, I need to fold it into a vb.net app and I'm running into the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when the app receives from the serial port.

Here's the code that fails

```
Private Sub ReadPort()

    While _keepReading
        If _serialPort.IsOpen Then
            Dim readBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(_serialPort.ReadBufferSize) {}
            Try
                ' If there are bytes available on the serial port,
                ' Read returns up to "count" bytes, but will not block (wait)
                ' for the remaining bytes. If there are no bytes available
                ' on the serial port, Read will block until at least one byte
                ' is available on the port, up until the ReadTimeout milliseconds
                ' have elapsed, at which time a TimeoutException will be thrown.
                Dim count As Integer = _serialPort.Read(readBuffer, 0, _serialPort.ReadBufferSize)
                Dim SerialIn As [String] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, count)
                DataReceived(SerialIn)

            Catch generatedExceptionName As TimeoutException
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            Dim waitTime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50)
            Thread.Sleep(waitTime)
        End If
    End While
End Sub`
```

DataReceived(SerialIn) throws the error.

Here's how it's designated as a delegate

```
 'begin Observer pattern
Public Delegate Sub EventHandler(param As String)
Public DataReceived As EventHandler
Public StatusChanged As EventHandler
```

I'm likely not getting something obvious but the various flavors of threading creation and interaction are fuzzy to me and I haven't been able to get past my error.

Any ideas why this throws the ubiquitous "Object reference not set..." error.   And yes, I do get that the object is not set. ;)

Here's what I'm attempting to call:

```
Friend Delegate Sub StringDelegate(ByVal strData As String)

Public Sub ReceiveFromServer(ByVal strDataIn As String)

    If Me.InvokeRequired() Then
        ' InvokeRequired: We're running on the background thread. Invoke the delegate.
        Me.Invoke(New StringDelegate(AddressOf ReceiveFromServer), New Object() {strDataIn})
    Else
        Dim i As Integer = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, don't implement your own Observer pattern.  Use the `Event` keyword instead, RaiseEvent to raise the event and you won't get NRE.  Or use the built-in SerialPort.DataReceived event instead of creating your own thread.  You are still going to have somebody subscribe the event, if the tree falls in the forest and there's nobody around then it doesn't make a sound.

Comment: That's reasonable and it may come to that.  However, I'm trying to work within the paradigm of the original C# code to maintain consistency.  Somewhere, somehow, I have created a problem porting from C# to vb.net. Everything else works - sending data is fine and the program receives data just fine too.  The only issue is handing it off to the rest of the app as the "listening" happens in a thread.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: There is no "paradigm" here, this was written by a programmer that did not understand events.  Typical Codeproject.com problem btw.  You have not shown any relevant code, the kind that subscribes the DataReceived "event" and does something with the received data  That does not help us help you.  Maybe you just didn't write it, most obvious explanation for the problem.

Comment: I don't know the programmer and I'm not particularly conversant with inter thread communication.  So I'm not a good one to evaluate his form.  I will only observe that I've adapted this with some changes (C#) to work successfully in a couple apps.  The use of "paradigm" was meant to be short hand for the idea that having a consistent pattern across platforms is helpful.  I've edited the above to include the code that's the intended target.  I will rewrite from scratch if need be but as above, I'd rather not.

Comment: Why port? If the existing code works as you want, why not drop the CommPort.cs file into a class library project, and then reference that c# class library dll in your vb project?

Answer (score 0):

Since getting done ultimately trumps maintaining consistency, I went ahead and restructured the delegate implementation. The routine listening on the serial port now looks like this:

```
 Public Delegate Sub DataReceived(ByVal MsgString As String)
Public Delegate Sub EventHandler(param As String)
```

(EventHandler is used elsewhere)

And:

```
   Private Sub ReadPort()

    Dim MessagePump As DataReceived
    MessagePump = AddressOf Serial_Port_UI.ReceiveFromServer

    While _keepReading
        If _serialPort.IsOpen Then
            Dim readBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(_serialPort.ReadBufferSize) {}
            Try
                ' If there are bytes available on the serial port,
                ' Read returns up to "count" bytes, but will not block (wait)
                ' for the remaining bytes. If there are no bytes available
                ' on the serial port, Read will block until at least one byte
                ' is available on the port, up until the ReadTimeout milliseconds
                ' have elapsed, at which time a TimeoutException will be thrown.
                Dim count As Integer = _serialPort.Read(readBuffer, 0, _serialPort.ReadBufferSize)
                Dim SerialIn As [String] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, count)
                MessagePump.Invoke(SerialIn)
                'DataReceived(SerialIn)

            Catch generatedExceptionName As TimeoutException
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            Dim waitTime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50)
            Thread.Sleep(waitTime)
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

This all produces the desired strings into the target Form/class like this:

```
   Public Delegate Sub StringDelegate(ByVal strData As String)

Public Sub ReceiveFromServer(ByVal strDataIn As String)

    If Me.InvokeRequired() Then
        ' InvokeRequired: We're running on the background thread. Invoke the delegate.
        Me.Invoke(New StringDelegate(AddressOf ReceiveFromServer), New Object() {strDataIn})
    Else
        Dim i As Integer = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks Hans for the help.